# What register state is saved on a context switch in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

Where in Linux would you look to find out what registers are saved on a context switch? I'm wondering, for example, if it is safe to use FP or vector registers in kernel-mode driver code (mostly interested in x86-64 and ARM, but I'm hoping for an architecture-independent answer).

Comment: You want to use FP registers to pass information back to usermode processes?

Comment: Presumably, doesn't the context switch have to save all registers? Otherwise you could never use a register that it does not save, because you never know when it's value might be overwritten.

Comment: @Justin: many OSes (including windows and linux) only save FPU/SSE registers after the first time they have been used by a process. This is because it is an expensive process that is relatively speaking rare.

Comment: I don't want to pass info back to usermode; I want to know if I can use the extra registers (or do FP math) in my driver.

Comment: @Evan - Cool. But how would the OS know that a register has been used?

Comment: @Justin: if the FPU state is uninitialized, an exception is thrown. The OS catches this, sets a "this thread used FPU flag", initializes the FPU state, and resumes the thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no one seems to have answered this, let me venture.

Take a look at the _math_restore_cpu and __unlazy_fpu methods.

You can find them here:

- http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/ident?i=math_state_restore
- http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/ident?i=__unlazy_fpu

The x86 like processors have separate instructions for saving (fnsave) and restore (frstor) FPU state and so it looks like the OS is burdened with saving/restoring them.

I presume unless the FPU unit has been used by the usermode process, linux context switch will not save it for you.

So you need to do it yourself (in your driver) to be sure. You can use kernel_fpu_begin/end to do it in your driver, but is generally not a good idea.

- http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/ident?i=kernel_fpu_begin
- http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/ident?i=kernel_fpu_end

Why it is not a good idea? From Linus himself: http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0405.3/1620.html

Quoted:

> You can do it "safely" on x86 using
>
> kernel_fpu_begin(); ...
>   kernel_fpu_end();
>
> and make sure that *all* the FP stuff
>   is in between those two things, and 
>   that you don't do *anything* that
>   might fault or sleep.
>
> The kernel_fpu_xxx() macros make sure
>   that preemption is turned off etc,  so
>   the above should always be safe.
>
> Even then, of course, using FP in the
>   kernel assumes that you actually
>   *have* an FPU, of course. The in-kernel FP emulation package is
>   *not* supposed to work with kernel FP instructions.
>
> Oh, and since the kernel doesn't link
>   with libc, you can't use anything 
>   even remotely fancy. It all has to be
>   stuff that gcc can do in-line, 
>   without any function calls.
>
> In other words: the rule is that you
>   really shouldn't use FP in the 
>   kernel. There are ways to do it, but
>   they tend to be for some *real* 
>   special cases, notably for doing
>   MMX/XMM work. Ie the only "proper" FPU
>   user is actually the RAID checksumming
>   MMX stuff.
>
> Linus

In any case, do you really want to rely on Intel's floating point unit? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug (just kidding :-)).