# Why aren't the FPU registers saved and recovered in a “context switch”?

Tags: assembly, x86, context-switch

As I know, during a context switch some registers are saved and recovered, but why the FPU registers don't ? 
Isn't there a huge risk of loosing their content if the schedulation comes at the wrong moment ?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006697/what-register-state-is-saved-on-a-context-switch-in-linux

Comment: Modern Linux uses "eager" FPU save/restore, not lazy, so the FPU registers *are* saved.  But there's no difference in risk; they're only restored if the kernel decides to actually schedule a different task.  For a lazy context switch, the kernel sets the FPU to fault if user-space tries to use it, so user-space can't use wrong values.  The only thing that can corrupt user-space FPU state is buggy kernel modules, see [Why am I able to perform floating point operations inside a Linux kernel module?](//stackoverflow.com/q/15883947).

Comment: This wasn’t widely known when Peter wrote his response, but in the new world of speculative execution attacks, lazy FPU context switching can leak some information.  See https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/security-center/advisory/intel-sa-00145.html and https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-3665 (the latter isn’t yet filled in, since it’s just now being made public).